# Even number of Parentheses (off by one)

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate the number of ways of making my ways though a grid in the shortest distance. The first grid is n x n and the formula of shortest ways through it is 2n choose n

(2n)!/((n+1)!(n!))

What do you do if the grid isn't square? n x (n + 1) grid. The shortest distance is 2n + 1

Thanks

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  ${2n \choose n}=\frac {(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$, unlike what you have written.  For an $n \times (n+1)$ grid, as you say you have $2n+1$ total moves, $n$ of which are in the short direction, so you have ${2n+1 \choose n}$ ways.